# Writing hebrew vowels with my phone keyboard

Tags: keyboard, hebrew

With my phone I can easily write English, French and Hebrew.  But I'm wondering if there is a possibility to add vowels to hebrew words, as it's possible with a keyboard with Windows.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to successfully type Hebrew with vowels on a Samsung using the steps I found on another forum:

> Since a few weeks ago it became possible to type vowels in the Gboard
>   app—Google's own keyboard. I strongly recommend it. I switched from
>   Samsung keyboard to it.
>
> To type the vowels, type the consonant first, and then hold down the
>   letter that begins the name of the vowel sign:
>
> Patakh, Hataf Patakh: פ
>
> Kamats, Hataf Kamats: ק
>
> Segol, Hataf Segol: ס
>
> Tsere: צ
>
> Hirik: ח
>
> Holam and Shuruq go with the letter Vav, so hold down Vav (ו) to type
>   them.
>
> Dagesh is the same character as Shuruq, and it's available also on
>   Dalet (ד).
>
> Kubuts is on ק, together with Kamats, even though it's a different
>   sound.
>
> For Shin and Sin dots, use the letter Shin (ש).
>
> A similar system exists on Windows since Windows 8, and on recent
>   desktop Linux systems (since 2013 or so). Use the Alt key and the
>   above letters to type the vowels.
>
> For Kubuts, use \ (the backslash; mnemonic: it's diagonal, like the
>   dots in Kubuts).
>
> For Shin and Sin dots, use the Q and W on a QWERTY keyboard (mnemonic:
>   they are above ש on the physical keyboard). For Hataf characters, use
>   the key to the right of the letter:
>
> Hataf Patakh: ]
>
> Hataf Kamats: ר
>
> Hataf Segol: ב

Taken from: https://www.duolingo.com/comment/21743347/Lack-of-Hebrew-vowels-on-keyboard

Comment: Uptoday it's possible with Google keyboard

Comment: @kouty Google keyboard doesn't work for me. Holding down shows the vowel options, but it quickly switches to the wrong option.